# VIM: Optional line range for command / function

Tags: vim

I have this in my `.vimrc` to remove trailing whitespace:

```
function! RemoveTrailingWhitespace()
  for lineno in range(a:firstline, a:lastline)
    let line = getline(lineno)
    let cleanLine = substitute(line, '\(\s\| \)\+$', '', 'e')
    call setline(lineno, cleanLine)
  endfor
endfunction
command -range RemoveTrailingWhitespace <line1>,<line2>call RemoveTrailingWhitespace()
command -range RT                       <line1>,<line2>call RemoveTrailingWhitespace()
```

This allows me to call `:'<,'>RT` to remove trailing whitespace for a visually selected range of lines. When i just call `:RT`, however, it only operates on the current line. What i want though, is to apply the command to the entire buffer. How can this be achieved?

Comment: FYI: There are several plugins that do that (and much more, like automatic triggering and highlighting of trailing whitespace). One of them is my [DeleteTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3967); it's page has links to alternatives.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

if you don't give `range`, the command with `range` will apply on current line. If you want to do it on whole buffer, use `:%RT` or `:1,$RT`

What you could do to make whole buffer as default range is:

```
command -range=% RT  <line1>,<line2>call RemoveTrailingWhitespace()
```

detail:

```
:h command-range
```

then you see:

```
Possible attributes are:

-range      Range allowed, default is current line
-range=%    Range allowed, default is whole file (1,$)
-range=N    A count (default N) which is specified in the line
        number position (like |:split|); allows for zero line
        number.
-count=N    A count (default N) which is specified either in the line
        number position, or as an initial argument (like |:Next|).
        Specifying -count (without a default) acts like -count=0
```

**one comment/question** to your function

if you have range info, why not just call vim-build in command `:[range]s` to do the substitution? then you could save those lines `getline`, `setline`, also the `loop`.

Comment: This seems to set the cursor position to the end of the file after running `:RT` without range. Do you know a way around this? I tried `getpos`/`setpos` as well as `winsaveview`/`winrestview`, but neither of them seemed to work. Thanks again!

Comment: Never mind, i followed your comment and rewrote the whole thing to use the `:s` command. Great suggestion!

Comment: @padde how did you call getpos/setpos? try `let x=getpos(".") [your logic stuff] then call setpos(".",x)`

Comment: Yes, but i guess the problem was that when the function is entered, the position is already at line 1. Cool thing is, using `:s` keeps the position anyway.

Comment: Damn, i just had a special case where the cursor position was correct 'by accident'. But adding | norm! `` did the trick :)

Answer (score 4):

In the end i went with this much simpler solution, which also keeps the cursor position:

```
command -range=% RemoveTrailingWhitespace <line1>,<line2>s/\(\s\| \)\+$// | norm! ``
command -range=% RT                       <line1>,<line2>RemoveTrailingWhitespace
```

Thanks for the suggestions @Kent!

Answer (score 0):

```
command! TrimAllWhitespace %s/\s\+$//
```